# how to display images stored in application directory

Tags: android

how to display images stored in **"/data/data/com.package/images/"** directory in a GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Create a bitmap drawable from the file:

```
BitmapDrawable d = BitmapDrawable.createFromPath("path");
```

Step 2) set this drawable on the image view of the corresponding grid item.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

On how to set imageview in grid view, please refer to this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: @mudit, Thank you for the response I tried but the emulator shows nothing my code is` BitmapDrawable d = (BitmapDrawable) BitmapDrawable.createFromPath("/data/data/com.dynamicView/XmlFiles/img.jpg");   imageView.setImageDrawable(d);`

Comment: @mudi this is the code: BitmapDrawable d = (BitmapDrawable) BitmapDrawable.createFromPath("/data/data/com.dynamic/XmlFiles/img.jpg"); 
 private Context mContext;
    public Source(Context c) {  mContext = c;    }
    public int getCount() {    return mThumbIds.length;    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {       return null;    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {     return 0;    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

Comment: Can you recheck that the image which you want to show is there and plus add some extra code; like how you are adding it in your gridview etc..

Comment: imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {imageView = (ImageView) convertView;}        
       imageView.setImageDrawable(d);return imageView;}

Comment: @mudi code for Activity class: setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
       GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new Source(this));

Comment: code looks fine to me.. now the only prob is image. Please recheck whether image is there or not; plus also debug the code and check the value of drawable that you are creating.

Comment: @mudi, thanks the code is working, and can u plz tell how to display all the images stored in that folder.